# How to separate date and time and show in separate columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a SQL Server table with a column `TaskAssignDate` which contains data like

```
2017-09-02 00:00:00.000
```

I want to separate date and time from that column and show the data in different columns.

I have a SQL query like this

```
select 
    TaskAutoId, UserAutoId,
    CONVERT(varchar, TaskAssignDate, 100) as TaskAssignDate,
    TaskDescription, TaskStartDate,
    CONVERT(varchar, TaskEndDate, 100) as TaskEndDate,
    IsCloseByUser
from 
    tblTask
where 
    IsSelfAssign = 1
```

I want to edit the following query, and split my column (`taskassigndate`) into two columns

What is a right way to do this?

Comment: Simply cast it in appropriate type like this - `SELECT TaskAutoId,UserAutoId,Cast(TaskAssignDate as date) AS TaskAssignDate,Cast(TaskAssignDate as time) AS AssignEndDate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CAST` and the appropriate datatype you want to cast to, `DATE` and `TIME`:

```
select TaskAutoId
    , UserAutoId
    , CONVERT(varchar, TaskAssignDate, 100) as TaskAssignDate
    , TaskDescription
    , TaskStartDate
    , CONVERT(varchar, TaskEndDate, 100) as TaskEndDate
    , IsCloseByUser
    , CAST(TaskAssignDate AS DATE) TaskAssignDate -- the date part
    , CAST(TaskAssignDate AS TIME) TaskAssignTime -- the time part
from tblTask
where IsSelfAssign = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 and up:

```
-- Select date
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);

-- Select time
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select TaskAutoId
    , UserAutoId
    , CONVERT(varchar, TaskAssignDate, 100) as TaskAssignDate
    , TaskDescription
    , TaskStartDate
    , CONVERT(varchar, TaskEndDate, 100) as TaskEndDate
    , IsCloseByUser
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TaskAssignDate, 101) TaskAssignDate -- the date    part
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TaskAssignDate, 108) TaskAssignTime -- the time part
from tblTask
where IsSelfAssign = 1
```