# how to split data to hourly based on start and end timestamp

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

My source data is like below

```
id      start_time              end_time
abc123  2022-07-03 12:00:00.0   2022-07-04 01:59:00.0
abc1234 2022-07-03 12:00:00.0   2022-07-04 01:59:00.0
abc123A 2022-07-03 13:00:00.0   2022-07-03 14:59:00.0
```

how to write a sql to get below output in hive. I am expecting sql should be dynamic since there is huge data

```
datetime              Count
2022-07-03 12:00:00   2
2022-07-03 13:00:00   3
2022-07-03 14:00:00   3
2022-07-03 15:00:00   2
2022-07-03 16:00:00   2
2022-07-03 17:00:00   2
2022-07-03 18:00:00   2
2022-07-03 19:00:00   2
2022-07-03 20:00:00   2
2022-07-03 21:00:00   2
2022-07-03 22:00:00   2
2022-07-03 23:00:00   2
2022-07-04 00:00:00   2
2022-07-04 01:00:00   2
```

Comment: have you seen these similar posts, [1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174035/split-duration-hourly-depending-on-start-and-end-time), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678551/splitting-date-into-2-columns-date-time-in-sql), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528056/how-to-separate-date-and-time-and-show-in-separate-columns-in-sql-server), [4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178059/how-to-split-24-hours-into-hour-slab-in-sql-server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing an inequality join with dimension gave me expected o/p

```
Dimension
+-------------------+
|start_time         |
+-------------------+
|2020-03-31 12:00:00|
|2020-03-31 13:00:00|
|2020-03-31 14:00:00|
|2020-03-31 15:00:00|
|2020-03-31 16:00:00|
|2020-03-31 17:00:00|
|2020-03-31 18:00:00|
|2020-03-31 19:00:00|
|2020-03-31 20:00:00|
|2020-03-31 21:00:00|
|2020-03-31 22:00:00|
|2020-03-31 23:00:00|
|2020-04-01 00:00:00|
|2020-04-01 01:00:00|
|2020-04-01 02:00:00|
|2020-04-01 03:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

Join Condition

```
tab.start_time <= dim.start_time and tab.end_time > dim.start_time
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick in Hive to generating a series of numbers -- and these can then be turned into dates.  This is a pain, but there is a trick using `space()` and `posexplode()` -- which is adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278300/how-to-generate-date-series-in-hive-creating-table/45279528).

I'm not sure if the syntax is 100% correct, but something like this:

```
with hh as (
      select unix_timestamp(min(start_time)) + (n - 1) * 60*60 as hh_start,
             unix_timestamp(min(start_time)) + n * 60*60 as hh_end
      from (select unix_timestamp(min(start_time)) as min_st,
                   floor((unix_timestamp(max(end_time)) - unix_timestamp(min(start_time))) / (60 * 60)) as num_hours
            from t
           ) x lateral view
           posexplode(split(space(num_hours + 1), ' ')) pe as n, x
     )
select hh.hh_start, count(t.id)
from hh left join
     t
     on t.start_time < hh.hh_end and
        t.end_time >= hh.hh_start
group by hh.hh_start
order by h.hh_start;
```